fflib Unit of Work Mocking with registerNew More Than Once with a Single Record
Having some issues mocking the below scenario. Let's say we are registering inserts for two objects and then relating them I'm unable to get the verifier to pass. I can only verify one record using fflib_Match.sObjectWidth and fflib_Match.sObjectsWith does not work since I'm not registering a list.
IApplicationSObjectUnitOfWork uow = Application.UnitOfWork.newInstance();
Case record = new Case(); // with other fields populated
EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(); // with other fields populated.
uow.registerNew(record);
uow.registerNew(message);
uow.registerRelationship(message, EmailMessage.ParentId, record);


You need to use [edit] to show your testmethod.  The short answer to your question is there is no issue verifying the above with apex mocks.

Thanks. I'll add my test method.

To supplement the answer by Andrew L and to answer his question in the comments...
The lines in the code-under-test
uow.registerNew(newMessage);
uow.registerRelationship(newMessage, EmailMessage.ParentId, newCase);

could be replaced by
uow.registerNew(newMessage, EmailMessage.ParentId, newCase);

and the mocks.verify you have:
((IApplicationSObjectUnitOfWork) mocks.verify(
        mockUow,
        mocks.times(1).description('email created')
    ))
    .registerNew(
        fflib_Match.sObjectWith(
            new Map<SObjectField, Object>{
                EmailMessage.FromAddress => existingMessage.FromAddress,
                EmailMessage.ToAddress => existingMessage.ToAddress,
                EmailMessage.Incoming => true,
                EmailMessage.Subject => existingMessage.Subject,
                EmailMessage.TextBody => existingMessage.TextBody,
                EmailMessage.HtmlBody => existingMessage.HtmlBody
            }
        )
    );
((IApplicationSObjectUnitOfWork) mocks.verify(
        mockUow,
        mocks.times(1).description('relationship created')
    ))
    .registerRelationship(
        fflib_Match.sObjectWith(
            new Map<SObjectField, Object>{
                EmailMessage.Subject => existingMessage.Subject
            }
        ),
        fflib_Match.eqSObjectField(EmailMessage.ParentId),
        fflib_Match.sObjectWith(
            new Map<SObjectField, Object>{
                Case.Subject => existingCase.Subject
            }
        )
    );

could be replaced with
((IApplicationSObjectUnitOfWork) mocks.verify(
        mockUow,
        mocks.times(1).description('EmailMessage parented to Case should be created')
    ))
    .registerNew(
        fflib_Match.sObjectWith(
            new Map<SObjectField, Object>{
                EmailMessage.FromAddress => existingMessage.FromAddress,
                EmailMessage.ToAddress => existingMessage.ToAddress,
                EmailMessage.Incoming => true,
                EmailMessage.Subject => existingMessage.Subject,
                EmailMessage.TextBody => existingMessage.TextBody,
                EmailMessage.HtmlBody => existingMessage.HtmlBody
            }
        ),
        fflib_Match.eqSObjectField(EmailMessage.ParentId),
        fflib_Match.sObjectWith(
            new Map<SObjectField, Object>{
                Case.Subject => existingCase.Subject
            }
        )
    );


I was able to get it work with sample code and test. Thanks.
public with sharing class SampleCaseAndEmailInsert {
    public static void execute(Case cs, EmailMessage message) {
        IApplicationSObjectUnitOfWork uow = 
        Application.UnitOfWork.newInstance();
        Case newCase = new Case(
            AccountId = cs.AccountId,
            ContactId = cs.ContactId,
            Status = 'New',
            Origin = cs.Origin,
            Subject = cs.Subject
        );
        EmailMessage newMessage = new EmailMessage(
            FromAddress = message.FromAddress,
            Incoming = true,
            ToAddress = message.ToAddress,
            Subject = message.Subject,
            TextBody = message.TextBody,
            HtmlBody = message.HtmlBody
        );
        uow.registerNew(newCase);
        uow.registerNew(newMessage);
        uow.registerRelationship(newMessage, EmailMessage.ParentId, newCase);
        uow.commitWork();
    }
}

Test class to verify mocks
@isTest
private class SampleCaseAndEmailInsertTest {
    @isTest
    static void testExecute() {
        fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();
        IApplicationSObjectUnitOfWork mockUow = (IApplicationSObjectUnitOfWork) mocks.mock(
        IApplicationSObjectUnitOfWork.class
        );
        Case existingCase = new Case(
        Id = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(Case.SObjectType),
        AccountId = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(Account.SObjectType),
        ContactId = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(Contact.SObjectType),
        Subject = 'Test Case',
        Origin = 'Manual'
    );
    EmailMessage existingMessage = new EmailMessage(
        Id = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(EmailMessage.SObjectType),
        FromAddress = 'from@example.com',
        ToAddress = 'to@example.com',
        Incoming = true,
        Subject = 'Test Subject',
        TextBody = 'Test Body',
        HtmlBody = '<p>Test Body</p>'
    );
    Application.UnitOfWork.setMock(mockUow);
    SampleCaseAndEmailInsert.execute(existingCase, existingMessage);
    ((IApplicationSObjectUnitOfWork) mocks.verify(
            mockUow,
            mocks.times(1).description('case created')
        ))
        .registerNew(
            fflib_Match.sObjectWith(
                new Map<SObjectField, Object>{
                    Case.AccountId => existingCase.AccountId,
                    Case.ContactId => existingCase.ContactId,
                    Case.Subject => existingCase.Subject,
                    Case.Origin => existingCase.Origin,
                    Case.Status => 'New'
                }
            )
        );
    ((IApplicationSObjectUnitOfWork) mocks.verify(
            mockUow,
            mocks.times(1).description('email created')
        ))
        .registerNew(
            fflib_Match.sObjectWith(
                new Map<SObjectField, Object>{
                    EmailMessage.FromAddress => existingMessage.FromAddress,
                    EmailMessage.ToAddress => existingMessage.ToAddress,
                    EmailMessage.Incoming => true,
                    EmailMessage.Subject => existingMessage.Subject,
                    EmailMessage.TextBody => existingMessage.TextBody,
                    EmailMessage.HtmlBody => existingMessage.HtmlBody
                }
            )
        );
    ((IApplicationSObjectUnitOfWork) mocks.verify(
            mockUow,
            mocks.times(1).description('relationship created')
        ))
        .registerRelationship(
            fflib_Match.sObjectWith(
                new Map<SObjectField, Object>{
                    EmailMessage.Subject => existingMessage.Subject
                }
            ),
            fflib_Match.eqSObjectField(EmailMessage.ParentId),
            fflib_Match.sObjectWith(
                new Map<SObjectField, Object>{
                    Case.Subject => existingCase.Subject
                }
            )
        );
    }

}


nice -- note that the registerNew method is overloaded so you can do uow.registerNew(newMessage,EmailMessage.ParentId,newCase) and you can then verify in one go rather than two.  Note also that the description(xxx) method in the mocks verify should say what should happen as in email message should be parented to new Case as it will display as part of the mock verify failure, if any.  This helps you and future devs know what should happen

Thanks for your help. Appreciate it.

Question though. How do you verify registerNew with two records when your are building a relationship as so?
